# Creating a header with a nav correctly?

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

This is what I am trying to create on my header. My problem with this is that I need help positioning the elements correctly. I can add the image logo and float:left; and then add  for the MOBILITY GROUP. I am not quite sure how to add my nav right in the location it is on the image. Also how to add the greeting on top right corner of the screen? Should I create two new divs for the greeting and the nav bar and give it absolute positioning?

As for the Logo it looks nice where it is from the JSFiddle example, but after the image is placed in the header there is some white space on the top of the header that is created and after adding the MOBILITY GROUP Title more white space is added? Why is that happening? My Title is also not centered along with the logo it is actually pushed closer to the top more?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waY4B/)

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="page">

      <div id="header">
              <p>
    <a href=""><img src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow.png" border=0></a>
    <h2><a href="" border=0>Mobility Group</a></h2>

              </p>
     </div>




    <div id="main">
    </div>




    <div id="footer">
    <h4>WNG Product Development Engineering (US)</h4>
    <a href="">Circuit</a>
    <a href="">Contact Us</a>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
        font-size:1em;
}
#page
{
        height:100%;
        min-width:960px;
}
#header
{
        background-color:#115EA2;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
}
#header img
{
        float:left;
        display:inline;
}
#header h2
{
        font-size:2.5em;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-decoration:none;
}
#main
{
        width:1300px;
        background-color:#F1F2F3;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
        color:#115EA2;
        text-decoration:none;
        min-height:950px;
}
#footer
{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        height: 35px;
        background-color:#115EA2;
}
#footer h4
{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
        float:left;
        color:#fff;
        margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}
#footer a
{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
        float:right;
        color:#fff;
        margin:10px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:active {color:#fff;}
#footer a:hover {color:#fff;}
#footer a:visited {color:#fff;}
```

Comment: It seems that the issue with the Logo and the title adding space on the top of the header is only happening to chrome and firefox browsers and not IE. It looks fine in IE.

Comment: The markup of the header of your page is incorrect. The `p` element can't contain the `h2` element, it will close implicitely before it so the end `</p>` tag becomes redundant. It's unlikely the reason of the current problem, but may lead to bad surprises in the future debugging.

Comment: I will try removing it and seeing if that does anything. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle based on your requirement. give this a shot. Fiddle link below

**HTML**

```
<header>

<div id="logo" class="push-left">

    <img src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow.png" width="120" height="100"/>

</div>

<div class="push-left head-text-fix">Mobility</div>

<div class="push-right" id="welcome-text">Welcome User</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="push-right menufix">

    <nav>

        <ul>

            <li>one</li>

            <li>two</li>

            <li>three</li>

            <li>four</li>

            <li>five</li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}

.push-left{
 float:left;
}

.menufix{background-color:green;margin-top:-38px;}

ul li{list-style:none;float:left;margin-left:15px}

.head-text-fix{
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:20px;
}

.push-right{
float:right;
}

#welcome-text{
margin-top:10px;
margin-right:15px;
}

.clearfix{clear:both};

#left-group{
width:300px;background-color:green;
}
```

Link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F8BZt/

Comment: The fiddle link you provided is incorrect. You have to save your work on fiddle before linking to it.